# How the TinyOS communicates with the TelosB hardware?

Tags: tinyos

I have a very basic question regarding how the whole system works for TelosB. I have gone through the data manual and how TelosB operates.

Now I need to send some specific data through the TelosB nodes. I saw the packet format of the TinyOS. and defined the payload.

```
  typedef nx_struct packet {
      nx_uint16_t id; /* Mote id of sending mote. */
      nx_uint16_t count; } packet_t;
```

In the radio count leds code I changed few small things

```
    #include "Timer.h"
    #include "RadioCountToLeds.h"



     module RadioCountToLedsC @safe() {
       uses {
       interface Leds;
      interface Boot;
       interface Receive;
        interface AMSend;
          interface Timer<TMilli> as MilliTimer;
         interface SplitControl as AMControl;
        interface Packet;
      }
        }
           implementation {

       message_t packet;

       bool locked;
     uint16_t counter = 0;

   event void Boot.booted() {
      call AMControl.start();
     }

      event void AMControl.startDone(error_t err) {
   if (err == SUCCESS) {
     call MilliTimer.startPeriodic(250);
     }
    else {
      call AMControl.start();
      }
     }

     event void AMControl.stopDone(error_t err) {
      // do nothing
      }

   event void MilliTimer.fired() {
      counter++;
     dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "RadioCountToLedsC: timer fired, counter is 
        %hu.\n", counter);
       if (locked) {
        return;
        }
         else {
          radio_count_msg_t* rcm = (radio_count_msg_t*)call 
  Packet.getPayload(&packet, sizeof(radio_count_msg_t));
  if (rcm == NULL) {
return;
  }

  rcm->counter = 11110000;
  if (call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(radio_count_msg_t)) == SUCCESS) {
dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "RadioCountToLedsC: packet sent.\n", counter); 
locked = TRUE;
  }
}
```

}

The counter is the data I want to transmit. It is 11110000. When this TinyOS code is run in the Telosb mote, how is the 11110000 interpreted? I need to be very specific about what data is going into the DAC of the telosb or OQPSK.

I want to know in details how the data is read and interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got my answer. cc2420 chip

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2420.pdf